# How do I make svn update prompt to resolve conflicts?

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I always use *svn update* from the command line in order to update my svn repo. However, we have a few files which always conflict, but which I generally always want to resolve immediately to mine. Until recently, whenever I ran *svn update* it would prompt me in-line for file resolutions. However, for some unknown reason it stopped recently, forcing me to resolve things in an extra separate step.

How do I re-enable the behavior where it will prompt in-line from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Check `--accept` option: it can be 'postpone' now, but 'edit'|'launch' before

Comment: is there a way to set that globally so it doesn't have to be specified on the command line?